# How can fast response time for one signal push notification for large data

Tags: php, android, mysqli, onesignal

using the One signal  for  sending the push notification  for android  application, i am using the rest API  in  PHP MYSQL for this  , but problem here  for large amount of data from MYSQL its response time increase, its take more time for  sending push to 1 million user .

Comment: Try using [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html)  in your query to reduce time response

Comment: i just need the hint .what can we do . thanks for your  response , sure this will work for me

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured correctly index on you mysql table?

`ALTER TABLE domains_table ADD INDEX (id);`

You must analyze your query, a million-row table is not very big.
Integer column for search are slightly more efficient if you not need other date from extra queries (other table).